# Open websites in R shiny app using webview or box container

Tags: android, r, webview, shiny, android-webview

If you run the R shiny script below, you get two boxes, the one box above is for entering the link, and the box below shows the webpage. However, I wish to get the entire functionality of the website occur within the lower box or a container like a "web view" in android. Currently, only few websites are getting displayed and the functionality of the website is also limited. Attaching the snapshot for reference, Please help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Web Site"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
box(title = "Web Site Search", status = "primary",height = "155" ,width = 
"355"
    ,solidHeader = T,
    uiOutput("search_this")),
box( title = "Web Page", status = "primary", height = "442px",width = 
"155",solidHeader = T, 
     uiOutput("wepPage"))))
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
output$search_this <- renderUI({
searchInput(inputId = "Id009", 
            label = "Enter the address",
            btnSearch = icon("search"), 
            btnReset = icon("remove"), 
            value='https://',
            width = "100%")
 })
  output$wepPage <- renderUI({
   return((HTML(readLines(input$Id009))))
  })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: webpage capture]

Comment: Wouldn't removing the `box` help? Or may be just have only one box in which  have both the `uiOutput`?

Comment: @SBista, Thank you so much for replying, I have no issues with that, but also, if you see, the link only provides a static page, I want a particular website to open up and work as fine as it works in a chrome browser, please help me out here.

Comment: @SBista, R has functions like shell.exec and browseurl to achieve this but in a browser window, I want to bring the site within R shiny itself and use it as fine as a browser.